# Codenameone : Android and IOS app crashes when navigating to maps page

Tags: codenameone

Android and IOS app crashes when navigating to maps page. But able to see the map in the simulator.
When I am looking for the problem in android, l found if from this declaration

```
 <uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
```

not exit in AndroidManifest.xml

When l looked at the previous source, I found that the declaration exit.

So I'm wondering if this declaration should be adding in the build server.
Thanks in advance for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see our support answered this issue.

This happened due to an `android.targetSDKVersion=28` which is smaller than API level 29 (the default now).

It triggers the stripping of that entry. This will be fixed to work for API level 28 too in the coming Friday release.